# Why $Z\times Z=(x,y|xy=yx)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have just studied "presentation of a group".

And this is an example in my text:

> $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\cong (x,y|xy=yx)$

Well, to me, a presentation of a group is much harder to imagine how the group looks like.. I have a trouble with visualizing it with a presentation.

How do I prove this?

And please give me some tips about making a presentation from a given group..

Comment: A group generated by two elements and with the only relation between them being commutativity = exactly the free abelian group of rank two.

Comment: @Timbuc I don't get it. $G=(x,y|xy=yx)$ means that $G$ is isomorphic to $F(\{x,y\})/N$ where $N$ is the normal closure of $\{xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\}$... How do you conclude that the relators say that $x,y$ are commutative??

Comment: Well, the generators commute since it is *given* $\;xy=yx\;$ ...why would I want to go with the free group in two elements and the normal closure and tough stuff if I have this easy?! Anyway, the normal closure of the relator $\;xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\;$ in the free group $\;F(x,y)\;$ is its commutator group, and thus $\;F/N=F/F'\;$ = the abelianization of that free group, and the result is the same.

Comment: @Timbuc I don't get that "why would I go with the tough stuff if I have this easy".. Isn't this just the definition of a presentation?

Comment: The way one usually avoids this kind of hard work is by using universal properties.  If I have group $G$ and a subset $S$, and I want to find the quotient $G\to G/N$, where $N$ is the normal closure of the subgroup generated by $S$... well, there's another description of this, namely it's the "universal" homomorphism $G\to H$, to some group $H$, that has $S$ in the kernel.

Comment: Here "universal" means that if I have some other group $K$, and another homomorphism $G\to K$, then there is one and only one way of factoring this map through the universal map: $G\to H\to K$.  If you get comfortable with this property, it makes it much easier to prove some things.  For example, it is fairly easy to show that a homomorphism $F(\{x,y\}) \to K$ that maps every $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ to $1$ must "pass through" the group $\mathbb{Z}x \oplus \mathbb{Z}y$ in a unique way. (and this kind of thing applies to non-free groups too; see "abelianizations")

Comment: But if someone claims to have a rigorous proof without dealing with words and without using universal properties, then I am doubtful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to give a "general" answer to this, because of nasty theoretic issues like the [word problem for groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups) which is the question of, "Given the presentation and two words, do the words represent the same element?" This is, in general, undecidable, which certainly complicates the question of determining what a presentation represents.

But, for simple presentations, you can make a list of some "canonical" form for every element. For instance, in
$$G=(x,y|xy=yx)$$
notice that every word is some product of $x$, $y$, $x^{-1}$, and $y^{-1}$, but since those commute, you can gather together all the $x$'s and all the $y$'s to give that every element can be written in the form $x^{a}y^{b}$ and the product of two elements is
$$(x^{a_1}y^{b_1})(x^{a_2}y^{b_2})=x^{a_1+a_2}y^{b_1+b_2}$$
which, clearly, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z\times Z}$, since the exponents are just adding. You could also think about the [Cayley graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) of the group in the presentation, and note that the presentation says that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is a cycle on the graph, and each of these cycles will look like a square, and you can recognize the resultant infinite grid as $\mathbb{Z\times Z}$.

If you want to find a presentation from a given group, a similar method in reverse is a good way; for instance, if you had the group $\mathbb{Z\times Z}$ and wanted to make a presentation, you could choose a set of elements which generate the group, like $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, and then figure out what relations hold between them. Unfortunately, this is not generally easy - it is not simple to determine whether you have enough relations to define the group, nor whether you have redundant relations included. Generally, some sort of proof is necessary, and the form of the proof may vary, but trying to find a canonical form is still a good idea.